# Help Identifying Small 4 pin male connector

Tags: connector

I'm trying to identify this connector so I can get an appropriate female connector for it. Its found on a Pico PSU (picoPSU-160-XT) next to the 12v input. There are 2 different ones on opposite corners. Mine is about 4 years old so it may be different than newer ones.

The dimensions of the connector are 12.5mm x 5.65mm and the pins are spaced 2.5mm apart.

UPDATE: For anyone looking for the female component for this connector, I found this: 
Digikey has the components (empty connector & pins), part #'s:

```
455-2267-ND
455-1135-1-ND
```

Or you can get this pre-made female connector with pigtails:
[JST-XH V2 4 Pin Adapter](http://www.all-battery.com/jst-xhv24pinadaptersforany3cellpack.aspx)

[image: JST-XH V2 4 Pin Adapter]

Comment: How far apart are pairs of pins, and how big is the whole socket? It *looks* like a common socket which comes in several different sizes. It looks like a socket where the pins are on 2mm centres.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I just updated post with that info. It does look very close to a fan or floppy connector but its not. I thought maybe they'd have an adapter for it on the site, but have looked before and found nothing.

Comment: JST 4-way? http://www.readymaderc.com/store/images/jst-xh.jpg

Comment: Wesley, that looks like it, do you have a link with the specs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That connector looks very like a [JST XH connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JST_connector)

The pitch is 2.5mm.

The JST web site can be searched for 'XH' [here](http://www.jst-mfg.com/index_e.php) 
Or the JST XH series is [here](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=277).

There is a [link to a downloadable PDF](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eXH.pdf) but it isn't clear that it is stable for the long term, so this link may break.

The engineering drawing "Through-hole type shrouded header", page 3, is 7mm high.

The datasheet has another drawing which says 9.8mm high on page 1, but that shows a plug in a socket, that drawing also shows 7mm as the height of the socket

Comment: I remeasured and got 2.5mm this time. Must be my wobbly hand, was using digital caliper. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Interesting though, the description says the height is 9.8mm and this is 7.5mm (just the white plastic part), not sure if they're including pins thru the hole, that seems closer. Anyway, you've got me on the right path.

Comment: @Proto - updated my answer to track your changes